# How to find data between two dates

Tags: php, sql

Hello there am trying to execute this query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  il_receipt WHERE recepit_date >='$search_date1' AND recepit_date <='$search_date2'" ;
```

But its not giving proper answer. 
EX. When i give inputs as 01/12/2015 and 02/12/2015 then its giving result including November's results between that two dates. Where it should has to give only December's dates. Please help me out with this, looking forward with reply.

Comment: Its probably assuming 12th of Januari, Are you comparing strings or datetimes?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The ANSI SQL date format is YYYY-MM-DD. (But many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time...)

Comment: we need to know what your column's data is and the type as well as how those variables are assigned as/from. It seems you're not paying attention to comments up here, so if and when these make it to you, adjust your question accordingly. voted to close the question as unclear.

Comment: `recepit` probable typo which grammatically speaking, should read as `receipt`.

Comment: good luck with that, I have moved on and closed this tab.

Comment: i have given datatype as VARCHAR

Comment: and my server is 
    Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
    Server type: MySQL
    Server version: 5.6.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
    Protocol version: 10
    User: root@localhost
    Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: i have used VARCHAR datatype for recepit

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BETWEEN statement :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM il_receipt WHERE recepit_date BETWEEN '$search_date1' AND '$search_date2'";
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Please see this: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: Hello Sir thanks for your reply. I have tried this one also, also i tried in both(BETWEEN and ,<=,>=) query on sql server its giving me the wrong answers.

Comment: Nothing wrong with BETWEEN... As always you need to know what you're doing... (Note that no dbms is tagged.)

Answer (score 0):

Your date format should be `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
"SELECT * FROM  il_receipt WHERE recepit_date between '$search_date1' AND '$search_date2'" ;
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be a solution to the problem, since it's just a different way of writing the same. Also, see this: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 0):

Considering your date is stored in `Y-M-D` in database, use this,

```
$search_date1 = date("Y-m-d",$search_date1);
$search_date2 = date("Y-m-d",$search_date2);
SELECT * FROM  il_receipt WHERE DATE(recepit_date) BETWEEN '$search_date1' AND '$search_date2';
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely one to do with formatting. I dont know what date format you are using so I wont guess at the correct one but you should have a look at your db model and see how the dates are being represented.

There does not appear to be anything wrong with your syntax. Make sure there are entries in the db that will return a clear result and make sure you have the format correct. Other than that it really should work.

You can use Between as others have mentioned but the way you are doing it should work just as well.

Edit: Given that you are using the VARCHAR datatype to store your dates you may have difficulty using mathematical operators and may have to get a bit clever about how you query your db. Try using the following where clause:

```
    WHERE receiptdate LIKE '%/12/%';
```

The LIKE keyword looks for a text pattern in a query. Use % before and after the desired pattern to tell the query that the desired pattern occurs with characters on either side(your day and year), and use the string /12/ to eliminate any 12s that show up in the day(very likely) or year(unlikely but you never know) sections. Techincally all of your dates in december should be represented like such:

xx/12/xxxx

That should return the results you desire :)

Comment: am using VARCHAR datatype instead of DATETIME, and not even i can go back and change that because there is a lot data base has been created.

Comment: Aha! There is your problem so. You are essentially saving your data as text but then trying to perform mathematical functions upon it. In text form the < and > operators are not going to understand the format of days/months etc. It will think 01/... is before 0/2... but never understand that the .../12/... part matters more than the day. I would suggest trying to use the LIKE keyword to find dates that contain your given month. Its hacky as all hell, but its a workaround :D

For example WHERE receiptdate LIKE %/12/% should find only dates in december